# Creating a vector using tree$edge rows

Tags: r, tree, phylogeny, ape

I would like to create a vector of names using the tree$edge rows of a phylogenetic tree. How can I construct this vector?
Example:

```
tree$edge # object
     [,1] [,2]
  [1,]   82   83
  [2,]   83   84
  [3,]   84   85
  [4,]   85   86
  [5,]   86   87
  [6,]   87   88
  [7,]   88   89
  [8,]   89   90
  [9,]   90   91
 [10,]   91    1
 [11,]   91   92
 [12,]   92    2
 [13,]   92   93
 [14,]   93   94
 [15,]   94    3
 [16,]   94    4
 [17,]   93   95
 [18,]   95   96
 [19,]   96    5
 [20,]   96    6
```

I would like to create a vector (that I call "vector_names) that each element is one of the rows of tree$edge.
I can do this doing row by row:

```
vector_names = c(paste(tree$edge[1,1],tree$edge[1,2], sep = "_"), 
               paste(tree$edge[2,1],tree$edge[2,2], sep = "_"),
               paste(tree$edge[3,1],tree$edge[3,2], sep = "_"),
                and so on until last row ....)
```

The result will be:

```
vector_names = 82_83, 83_84, 84_85, 85_86, etc.
```

but is a long table with 161 rows and I would like to know if there is a faster way to produce the vector_names above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you can try `fread` from `data.table` like below

```
tree <- as.matrix(fread(text = paste0(paste0(vector_names, "\t")), sep = "_"))
```

or `read.table` from base R

```
tree <- as.matrix(read.table(text = paste0(paste0(vector_names, "\t")), sep = "_"))
```

which gives

```
     V1 V2
[1,] 82 83
[2,] 83 84
[3,] 84 85
[4,] 85 86
```

---

**Update**

If you want to get `vector_names` from tree, you can try

```
> do.call(paste, c(data.frame(tree), sep = "-"))
[1] "82-83" "83-84" "84-85" "85-86"
```

**Data**

```
vector_names <- c("82_83", "83_84", "84_85", "85_86")

tree <- structure(c(82, 83, 84, 85, 83, 84, 85, 86), .Dim = c(4L, 2L))
```

Comment: thanks but I think this not answer my question. I edit my post to make it clear. I don't have a ```vector_names```. I want to create one by using the rows of tree$edge object.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `strsplit` to split by `_` and then `rbind` the `list` elements

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(strsplit(vector_names, "_"), as.numeric))
```

#### data

```
vector_names <- c("82_83", "83_84", "84_85", "85_86")
```

Comment: thanks. I edit my post to make it clear. I have the object ```tree3$edge``` and want to use each row of it to create ```vector_names```.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest and most computationally efficient approach would be
`apply(tree3$edge, 1, paste0, collapse = '_')`